# Linq order list using list property

Tags: c#, linq

If i have a list of football teams, and each team contains a list matches. If each match has a property of goals scored, how can i order the list of football teams so that it is ordered by the most goals scored in the lastest match, followed by the match before and so on? 
The number of matches is unknown.

I cant figure out the linq and im not having much luck with investigating dynamic linq

Many thanks

The number of matches will always be the same and theoretically there isnt a maximum although it is reasonable to expect that it will be less than 20. If the number of goals is the same it will use team name in alphabetical order.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of matches?  What should you do if one team has more games than another?

Comment: show us what you've tried, even if you couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I have editted the original post

Comment: Please post some code (sample data in test objects) and your tries.

Answer (score 1):

Linq doesn't do recursion natively.  You may need to define a custom comparer in order to to the recursive search, then pass that to `OrderBy`.  Without seeing the actual structure the pseudo-code would be:

```
N = 1
while(true)
{
   if L has less than N matches
       if R has less than matches
           return L.Name.CompareTo(R.Name)  // order by team name
       else
           return 1 // R has more matches

   if R has less than matches // L has more matches
        return -1

   compare Nth match of each team
   if equal
       N = N + 1; 
   else
       return compare result
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. What part makes you think this requires recursion?

Comment: @Aducci the comparison is "compare the scores of the latest match for each team - then the match before, then the match before, etc."   So a recursive comparison is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion seems to not be necessary.  Here's an iterative approach.

```
void Main() {
    var teams = CreateTeams().ToArray();
    int games = teams.Min(t => t.Games.Count);
    var ordered = teams.OrderBy(team => 0);

    for (int i = games - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var captured = i; // the value of i will change, so use this capturing variable, 
        ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(team => team.Games[captured].Points);
    }
    ordered = ordered.ThenBy(team => team.Name);

    foreach (var team in ordered) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", team.Name, string.Join(", ", team.Games.Select(game => game.Points)));
    }
}

IEnumerable<Team> CreateTeams() { 
    yield return (new Team("War Donkeys", 1, 2, 3));
    yield return (new Team("Fighting Beavers", 2, 2, 3));
    yield return (new Team("Angry Potatoes", 2, 1, 3));
    yield return (new Team("Wispy Waterfalls", 3, 2, 1));
    yield return (new Team("Frisky Felines", 1, 2, 3));
}

class Team {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Game> Games { get; set; }

    public Team(string name, params int[] points) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Games = points.Select(p => new Game { Points = p }).ToArray();
    }
}

class Game {
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

The output is

```
Fighting Beavers 2, 2, 3
Frisky Felines 1, 2, 3
War Donkeys 1, 2, 3
Angry Potatoes 2, 1, 3
Wispy Waterfalls 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Yes.  The order is first based on the latest match, as specified in the question.

Comment: Wispy waterfalls got 1 point in the last match, which is the least of any team, so I think they should be ordered last.

Comment: I think you are right. I am having trouble wrapping my head around this question